# Double hat when usercard appears for the first time

Tags: bug, winter-bash, user-card

When mouse hover over a user with a worn hat and available usercard ([Established User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)) then:

- for the first time after page load you can see a double hat:

> [image: double]

- for the next time hat appears only in the usercard:

> [image: single]

Same effect could be observed on the [review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review).

Comment: That's user card, not flair.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanx for fix. I just realized my mistake :) And now it is possible to reproduce bug right here!

Comment: I see it every time. Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 50.1.0

Comment: That extra hat is actually the hat from the avatar...

Comment: @PythonMaster what do you mean? I don't have hat in my avatar. [Here is another, better, example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AQvP.png) of the bug.

Comment: @PythonMaster you are right. See my diagnosis in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because initially the hat is rendered on the user avatar. Once the large user card is shown, that rendering remains, so it looks like the hat is rendered twice on the user card, which it isn't. It just sits in the background.

After the user card is sized down, the original hat on the avatar isn't used any more. The resized hat from the user card is. Hence it doesn't show the second time around.

This could be 'fixed' by removing the hat in the background when the user card is opened, not closed.