# Close question about winter bash as "can no longer be reproduced"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, winter-bash

My [post about hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289136/339911) has one close vote as "off-topic" because "can no longer be reproduced". And now this is definitely true. No one has hats.

> [image: off-topic]

Should a post about *Winter bash* be closed as off-topic ("can no longer be reproduced") when *Winter bash* season is over? Should it be reopened in the next season? Or is this a some kind of voter's joke? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They shouldn't be closed at all unless they were specific to that year's Winterbash (let's be honest, few are). Bug reports especially are still entirely relevant things that developers could fix before the next Winterbash starts up, so they should be open and answerable. Cycling through closed and open states depending on whether it's running right now is a waste of time.

Comment: Please convey your point of view to the close-voter.

Comment: @alexolut not sure there's a point to do that. The close vote will expire at some point, and single close vote has no real effect anyway (the item [has been removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/48936) already from the Close review). If the close voter is active on MSE, he/she will see this answer on their own.