# Should we close old Winter Bash questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, meta, off-topic, winter-bash

I see a few questions in the Close Votes review queue here on Meta Stack Exchange for specific questions about the challenges and rewards of Winter Bashes gone by. Some people are voting to close them using the "can no longer be reproduced" reason. In a sense that's true - Winter Bash 2018 and before are gone, and no amount of unicorn sparkle pony dust will bring them back. On the other hand, the old questions don't seem to be doing much harm and it is theoretically possible for someone to find something new about those old events through data mining.

**Should we close these questions?**

Comment: Does this help? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290660/369802

Answer (score 10):

## No

They were relevant at the time and Meta is not the same as a coding problem. It also messes with people's question records for no good reason. Just let them fade into obscurity.

Answer (score 6):

## NO

I might be biased, as can clearly be seen from this year's WB prior year's hats are still very much relevant and important.
There is no need to "close" old WB hat lists, or other questions about WB bugs. It's the history of the WB, I see no need to close it now even if it "can no longer be reproduced."

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

If what the question is asking about can no longer be reproduced, then there is no point leaving such questions open for new answers and close votes are appropriate.

Unless they are also deleted, these questions remain on the site, and are still available to be found by searches and data mining.